# TensorFlow: how to efficiently train a network where each layer needs feeding?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Typically, the only feeding for a standard network implementation is for the inputs/labels. You have the input and label/truth as placeholders, and pass the concrete data to the `feed_dict` for training loops.

My model is composed of multiple networks, like a network where each layer is itself a network. Each layer-network in the model accepts two inputs: a data input and an adjacency list for graph convolutions.

If the only input needed was the data inputs, I would not be having issues with using placeholders, since there is no need for feeding between the model's layer-networks. However, the adjacency lists are created by `numpy` and `sklearn` functions that need true data inputs (as in, numpy arrays) instead of placeholder tensors.

My network looks something like this:

```
# <make X* and alist* inputs placeholders>

# forwad through the layer-networks
H1 = network_fwd(X0, alist0, var_scope=SCOPE.format(0)) # params_0/*
H2 = network_fwd(H1, alist1, var_scope=SCOPE.format(1)) # params_1/*
H3 = network_fwd(H2, alist2, var_scope=SCOPE.format(2))
# ...
H10 = network_fwd(H9, alist9, var_scope=SCOPE.format(9))

# optimize on sum network error
error = loss_fn(H1, X1)
error += loss_fn(H2, X2)
error += loss_fn(H3, X3)
#...
error += loss_fn(H10, X10)

train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)

# train
for step in range(num_steps):
    x_batch = numpy_ops.next_minibatch(X_train, mb_size) # list of data inputs

    # fill placeholders for true inputs X0, X1, ..., X10
    fdict = {placeholder_name: x for placeholder_name, x in zip(pnames, x_batch)}

    # layer-network predictions and adj lists
    adj_list0 = numpy_ops.get_adjacency_list(x_batch[0], K)
    fdict[alist0] = adj_list0
    #=====================================
    h1 = sess.run(H1, feed_dict=fdict)
    fdict[alist1] = numpy_ops.get_adjacency_list(h1, K)
    #=====================================
    h2 = sess.run(H2, feed_dict=fdict)
    fdict[alist2] = numpy_ops.get_adjacency_list(h2, K)
    # ...

    # and finally the actual training pass
    train.run(feed_dict=fdict)
```

I've made things explicit in my example code with hardcoded lines, so I don't need cleanup tips on that. The problem is that each `network_fwd` requires feeding for `alist`, so each previous prediction/output is recomputed for every subsequent layer-network to get the next layer's adjacency list on the previous layers output.

It's horribly inefficient, but I cannot use tensorflow ops for the adjacency list functions. Is there any way to do a single pass through the model's networks (computing each `H*` only once)?

In runtime autodiff frameworks like Chainer, this would not be an issue since you can just do the adjacency list function or whatever other non-framework data processing functions during forward execution, but I'm really stumped with how to do this in TF.

Comment: You say you cannot use tensorflow ops for the adjacency list functions. Why is that?

Comment: @mikkola: The adjacency list functions call on `sklearn.neighbors` functions. These are high level functions that wrap highly optimized (cython) nearest neighbor searches and distance metric functions. With low dimensional toy data, TF ops can probably be used, but I often run into memory issues with pairwise distance functions, since a single data sample has approximately 32^3 points. Efficiently implementing these functions in TF would require an entire suite of supporting functions, and probably require the concerted effort of a group. I am a mere mortal.

Comment: Did you consider wrapping these functions using [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func)?

Comment: No, I did not know about `tf.py_func`, but it looks promising. I am new to tensorflow; thank you for sharing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@mikkola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5471520/mikkola)'s suggestion to wrap the functions with [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) worked for me.

How I used `tf.py_func`:

```
# <initialize all child network variables>

# make adjacency list function interface for tf.py_func
def alist_func(h_in):
    """ Given constraints on the input to the func arg in tf.py_func,
        you may need to interface the numpy function if it's signature
        has other args or kwargs
    """
    return numpy_ops.get_adjacency_list(h_in, K)

# direct graph
data_in_shape = (11, None, num_points, D)
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=data_in_shape, name='X_input')
X_pred, loss = tensor_ops.multi_func_model_fwd(X_input, var_scopes, alist_func)

# optimizer
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# train
for step in range(num_steps):
    x_batch = numpy_ops.next_minibatch(X_train, mb_size) # list of data inputs
    train.run(feed_dict={X_input: x_batch})



# in tensor_ops script, this is how I use tf.py_func
def meta_model_fwd(x_in, var_scopes, alist_fn, *args, **kwargs):
    alist = tf.py_func(alist_fn, [x_in[0]], tf.int32) # inp is float32, out is int32
    h = model_fwd(x_in[0], alist, var_scopes[0], *args, **kwargs)
    loss = loss_fn(h, x_in[1])
    for idx, vscope in enumerate(var_scopes[1:]):
        alist = tf.py_func(alist_fn, [h], tf.int32)
        h = model_fwd(h, alist, vscope, *args, **kwargs)
        loss += loss_fn(h, x_in[idx+1])
    return h, loss
```

Thanks again mikkola!